# Apache DButils column mapping on insert/update?

Tags: java, apache-commons-dbutils

Apache DBUtils' `BeanHandler` can conveniently map data into a bean when using SELECT queries. However, it does not seem to be able to do the same when writing data, so I need to use an error-prone way:

```
newid = qRunner.insert("insert into table(field1Name, field2Name, ... field5Name) values(?,?,?,?,?)",
        new ScalarHandler<Long>(), field1Value, field2Value, ... field5Value);
```

For tens of columns, it's easy to mess up the pairing of question marks to column values. Is there a similar lightweight library or some kind of extension to DBUtils that can map fields in both directions? (I know Hibernate, but it's way too heavy for my project.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it too late for my project, but [Persism](http://sourceforge.net/p/persism/wiki/MappingRules/) seems to be able to handle what I need without the hassles of Hibernate.